# Actualización de las opciones de campo en base a una selección con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, eloquent, html-select

A partir de [este artículo](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-dynamic-dependant-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-example-part-2example.html) encontré una forma interesante de crear cajas de selección dinámicas. Conseguí adaptarlo a mi caso, acrescentando a rotas/web.php

```
Route::post('select-ajax', ['as'=>'select-ajax','uses'=>'SpecificController@myformAjax']);
```

y generar caídas de selección dinámicas que tengan como valores el `organization_id` como el siguiente estaba en mi controlador

```
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        $campusorganizations = DB::table('campus_organizations')->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->pluck("organization_id", "id")->all();
        $data = view('ajax-select',compact('campusorganizations'))->render();
        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

e este es el `ajax-select.blade.php`.

```
@if(!empty($campusorganizations))
  @foreach($organizacionesdecampus como $clave => $valor)
    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

e o AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select[name='campus_id']").change(function(){
        var campus_id = $(this).val();
        var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo route('select-ajax') ?>",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {campus_id:campus_id, _token:token},
            success: function(datos) {
                $("select[name='campus_organization_id'").html('');
                $("select[name='campus_organization_id'").html(data.options);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Este fue el resultado

[image: introduzca la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La pregunta es que quiero tener el nombre de la organización en lugar de su ID.

Dado que en mi modelo `CampusOrganization` tengo

```
/**
 * Obtener la organización
 *
 * @return \Organization
 */
function public organization()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
}
```

de donde se puede obtener el nombre de la organización.

Así, adapté el `ajax-select.blade.php` para

```
<option value=''>Ninguna</opción>
@if(!empty($campusorganizations))
  @foreach($organizacionesdecampus como $organizacióndecampus)
    <option value="{{ $campusorganization->id }}">{{ $campusorganization->organization->name }}</option>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

y el controlador para

```
/**
 * Obtener la solicitud Ajax y devolver los datos
 *
 * @return \NIlluminate\Http\Response
 */
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){

        $campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->get();

        $data = view('rooms.ajax-select', $campusorganizations)->render();

        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

pero ahora lo que recibes es (sin opciones)

[image: introduzca aquí la descripción de la imagen]

También he probado con

```
$campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::with('organization')->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)->get();
```

pero tampoco se dieron resultados.

---

---

### Edit

Si devuelvo `$campusorganizations`

```
/**
 * Get Ajax Request and return Data
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function myformAjax(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){

        $campusorganizations = CampusOrganization::with('organization:id,name')
                                ->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)
                                ->with('organization')
                                ->get();

        return $campusorganizations;

        $data = view('rooms.ajax-select',$campusorganizations)->render();

        return response()->json(['options'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

entonces tengo en la respuesta

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "campus_add_users": 0,
    "campus_id": 4,
    "organization_id": 4,
    "created_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:42.000000Z",
    "organization": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Aldi",
      "slug": "aldi",
      "is_visible": 1,
      "user_id": 2,
      "created_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:38.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-12T20:15:38.000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Después de eliminar `return $campusorganizations;`, la respuesta será

```
{"options":"<option value=''>None<\/option>\r\n"}
```

[image]

---

Tenga en cuenta que al responder a esta pregunta también podrá responder (puedo ayudar con el portugués y el Inglés)

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499616/116751
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/66652922/5675325

Comment: La consulta con `with` ¿qué resultados devolvió?

Comment: @BetaM acabo de añadir más información

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, el nombre de tu organización está en otra tabla relacionada con esta tabla campus_organization, Imaginando que tus relaciones estén correctas (ya que veo que tienes una función con acentos. Laravel por recomendación pide que manejes todo en inglés, es decir, tu función debería llamarse organization), deberías cargar tus relaciones al momento de hacer la consulta. Es decir, hacer algo como esto:

```
CampusOrganization::with('organization')
    ->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)
    ->get();
```

O en su defecto, si quieres solo traer el nombre, puedes hacer:

```
CampusOrganization::with('organization:id,name')
    ->where('campus_id',$request->campus_id)
    ->get();
```

Si necesitas más referencias, puedes consultar [acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Además, en lugar de

```
$data = view('rooms.ajax-select',$campusorganizations)->render();
```

debes nombrar la variable así

```
$data = view('rooms.ajax-select',['campusorganizations'=>$campusorganizations])->render();
```

Eso va a ser suficiente entonces

[image]

---

Edito un poco la respuesta porque creo que no estás viendo muy bien cómo funcionan también los objetos en JavasScript (JSON).

Si lo ves, lo que te devuelve es un array de objetos (JSON) el cual te da sus atributos. Entonces, al obtenerlos de esa manera vía AJAX, solo debes accederlos de esta forma: `datos.res[0].organitazion.name`

Yo uso fetch y paso a dejarte un ejemplo.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    datos: []
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        
        this.datos = res.results
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <p> {{ datos[0].episode[0] }} </p> Accedes a la propiedad de un objeto según sus indices en el array

 (O lo recorres y vas accediendo a cada una de sus propiedades)
  <div v-for="dato in datos"> 
    <p> {{ dato.name }} | {{ dato.status }} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

En Laravel es lo mismo (más allá de que yo en mi ejemplo usé vuejs), es decir, si estás usando blade, solo debes ingresar a las propiedades del objeto así en tu foreach:

```
@foreach($campusorganizations as $campus)
    <p> {{ $campus->organization->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Eso debería mostrarte el campo name. En el enlace que te dejé habían ejemplos directamente de la documentación que te podían servir.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Oh, eran problemas de traducción, ¡ya están arreglados! ya había probado con `with` pero no devolvió valores...

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 recuerda marcar como respuesta con el check si crees que respondio tu pregunta

Comment: el upvote fue solo por tu esfuerzo porque no resolvió mi problema

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 edité un poco mi respuesta para ayudarte un poco más

Comment: ya ha conseguido resolver y ha editado su respuesta para contemplar la solución. muy agradecido